# Getting the same content when refreshing a page after filtering some data with ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Here is my situation:

In the center of the page, i have the content dir: `<div id="content"></div>`

In the right side of the page, i have a `<form method="post" action="?p=search">` with some input fields and a submit button: `<input type="submit" id="searchButton" />`.

I'm doing an AJAX request when submitting the form to the `index.php`, just because the index loads all my environment and then it includes the `search.php` and exits.

The `search.php` file returns with **json** an array returned by a query sent to the database.

With this return, when the request ends, i update my content div with the data.

But i didn't realize that, if i just reload the page, without clicking in the search button, all my search goes away, it just returns the main content query made by the default page..

How can i fix it? Is there a good practice for that?

Thanks, thanks and thanks.

Comment: when do want it to reload? I assume you want to click the submit button and do the AJAX request and after that add the data to your page?

Comment: Yes, that is what i am doing. But when i reload the page, just pressing 'F5' or something like that, i won't get the same result, because the ajax request is done just when submitting the form..

Comment: True. There's nothing (in my knowlegde) you can do about that. When you're reloading your page, as you said, all the data you submitted trough your form are gone. Could you explain your situation, why do you want to reload the page?

Comment: I don't want to do it, but imagine that an user is searching for a content, then he wants to just reload the page.. All his search will be gone, i just want to handle this kind of situation.. But i don't know how yet.

Comment: What you maybe could do: change your form method from 'POST' to 'GET'. All the data he filled in the form will be accessible from your URL. So you can even get the data after refresh with PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add initial when try ajax in search.

When initial is not null call your ajax again, try `$(window).load(function ()` to detect your initial.

You can choose cookie for initial.

for example :

> ```
>   //assume this call your ajax
>
>   var ajax_search = function(str) {
>       $.ajax({
>         type: "POST",
>         url: "some.php",
>         data: $str
>       }).done(function( msg ) {
>         alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
>         setCookie("IsSubmitSearch", "true", 1);
>       });
>   }
>
>   // when click submit search
>   $("#search").click(function() {
>       var str = $("#inputSearch").serialize();
>       ajax_search(str);
>
>       return false;
>   });
>
>   $(window).load(function () {
>       var IsSubmitSearch = getCookie("IsSubmitSearch");
>       if (IsSubmitSearch != null && IsSubmitSearch != "") {
>           //cookie exists then you refreshed this page(F5, reload button or right click and reload)
>           //SOME CODE
>           var str = $("#inputSearch").serialize();
>           ajax_search(str);
>           DeleteCookie("IsSubmitSearch");
>        }
>        else {
>           //cookie doesnt exists then you landed on this page
>           //SOME CODE
>           setCookie("IsSubmitSearch", "true", 1);
>        }
>   });
> ```

Comment: Thanks @hendrathings, i'll try to do something like this with my session.